# how to create independent list of list

Tags: python, list, graph

I want to read a graph, whose vertexes are numbered 0..n-1. I tried the following code:

```
myfile = open('test.in', 'r')
n = int(myfile.readline())
graph = [[]]*n
for line in myfile:
    u, v, w = map(int, line.strip().split(' '))
    graph[u].append((v, w))
print graph
```

but it doesn't work well. I found that all elements in `graph` are the same! Then I use the following code to fix it:

```
road = [[] for i in xrange(n)]
```

It does work, but looks not so pretty.

I want to know **if there is a better solution to this situation** and **why all elements are the same in the first code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
from collections import defaultdict
graph = defaultdict(list)
```

The reason that `graph = [[]]*n` doesn't work is that you are creating a single empty list and then making many references to that same list

Comment: thanks a lot. i have used `defaultdict` before, but i guess that list would be little faster than dict since vertexes are numbered 0..n-1. am i right?

Comment: @abcdabcd987, "fast" and "pretty" are not orthogonal. Often you have to trade one for the other or find a compromise